# How to get creation date of a folder using scom

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, folder, scom

How can I get a folder's creation date using scom-c#

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to get the creation date of folder:

```
item.Folder.Item["Created"]
```

Comment: item.Folder.Item doesn't exist: